# Querying Salesforce Campaigns for Newly Added Contacts

Tags: rest-api, rest, sobject, campaign

I'd like to pull all of the contacts who have recently been added to a campaign using HTTP requests (from an external application). My current method is using a `GET` request with the URL `/sobjects/Campaign/updated?start=2020-04-23T00:00:00Z&end=2020-04-26T23:59:59Z` (with example dates in their for the purpose of discussion).

Is there a better way to do this from outside of Salesforce? I'm writing a script to integrate my application with Salesforce.

Comment: you should be looking at `CampaignMember` where CreatedDate is within daterange. what you have tells you when a Campaign was updated, not which members

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) as an option. With Change Data Capture, you receive near-real-time changes of Salesforce records, changes include the creation of a new record, updates to an existing record, deletion of a record, and undeletion of a record.

Campaign Members are [supported](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_object_support.htm) in Change Data Capture.

I would also suggest reviewing the [limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_allocations.htm)